# Unable to return response of mongoDB save call to frontend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to NodeJS and learning how to make a DB call.

My DB call is working and the request to save data are reflected in the DB. I want to send the response of **save call** to the client(frontend)

But I am unable to return the response. The **await** doesn't seem to work in file1.

Any help or reference is appreciated.

My code

**file1 with DB connection and calling the file2 that has save call**

```
app.post('/',async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        const val = await gameEngine.processRequest(req.body,res);
       console.log(val) // prints { status: 'READY', token: Promise { <pending> } }
        res.json(val);
    } catch(err) {
        res.json({message:err });
    }
});
```

**file2 where the save call occurs**

```
async function processRequest(body,res){
    if(body.Request === "START")
    {
        return await {"status":"READY", "token":getNewDBToken(res)};
    }
    return {"status":"Invalid"};
}
async function getNewDBToken(res) {
    try{
        const status = new statusDataBase({gameStatus: createBoard()});
        const saved = await ((status.save()));
        console.log(saved);   // prints the response as expected.
        return await saved;
    }
    catch(err)
        {res.json({message: "err1"});}
}
```

Noticed that although the console.log in file2 is called first, it gets logged after the file1's console log.

Comment: have tried using await in all places.

Comment: had gone through [this](https://javascript.info/async-await) but couldn't figure the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.

```
return {"status":"READY", "token": await getNewDBToken(res)};
```

`await` only awaits on promises, not objects containing promises as properties.

```js
async function run() {
  const wrong = await {
    test: delay(1000, 'wrong'),
    wrong: true,
  };
  console.log(wrong)

  const right = {
    test: await delay(500, 'right'),
    right: true,
  }
  console.log(right)
}

run();




function delay(ms, value) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms, value)).then(x => { console.log(`Value ${value} returned after ${ms} ms.`); return x;})
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. 'await' had to be placed in just 2 lines, one in the line posted by you. Second in the line "await gameEngine.processRequest(req.body,res);" of file 1.

Comment: @DarshanKN Technically you can place await wherever you want. For example `const a = [ await 1, await 2, await 3, {[await 'name']: await 'value'}]` is valid js. But it only makes sense when applied to "thenable" value (most common a Promise)

Comment: I doesn't return the DB response unless "await" is in the line "await gameEngine.processRequest(req.body, res);"

Answer (score 1):

In File2

try like this,

```
async function processRequest(body,res){
    if(body.Request === "START")
    {
       let newToken = await getNewDBToken(res)
        return await {"status":"READY", "token":newToken};
    }
    return {"status":"Invalid"};
}
async function getNewDBToken(res) {
    try{
        const status = new statusDataBase({gameStatus: createBoard()});
        const saved = await ((status.save()));
        console.log(saved);   // prints the response as expected.
        return await saved;
    }
    catch(err)
        {res.json({message: "err1"});}
}
```

Note: When you are calling `Async function` without `await` or any Promise Then It Returns
Promise { pending }